# Split part function in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How do I split the zipcode and state in this table? I had no trouble separating the street and city, but I struggled with the ZIP code and State part

944 Walnut Street, Boston, MA 02215
This should be the output:

```
|       Street     | City | State | ZipCode
:------------------:------:-------:-------:
| 944 Walnut Street|Boston|  MA   | 02215
```

I tried doing this but this is the result

```
SELECT
    split_part(purchaseaddress::TEXT, ',', 1) Street,
    split_part(purchaseaddress::TEXT, ',', 2) City,
        split_part(purchaseaddress::TEXT, ',', 3) State,
        split_part(purchaseaddress::TEXT, ' ' , 4)ZIPCode
FROM
    sales_2019;
```

```
|       Street     | City |    State   | ZipCode
:------------------:------:------------:-------:
| 944 Walnut Street|Boston|  MA 02215  | Boston,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT
trim(split_part(purchaseaddress::TEXT, ',', 1)) Street,
trim(split_part(purchaseaddress::TEXT, ',', 2)) City,
trim(split_part(trim(split_part(purchaseaddress::TEXT, ',', 3))::TEXT, ' ', 1)) State,
trim(split_part(trim(split_part(purchaseaddress::TEXT, ',' , 3))::TEXT, ' ', 2)) ZIPCode
FROM
sales_2019;
```

output:-

```
        street       |  city  | state | zipcode
   ------------------+--------+-------+---------
   944 Walnut Street | Boston |   MA  | 02215
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) split it once, then pick the fields by index.
2. Make sure you [`trim()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) the elements before trying to split by space to avoid empty leading and trailing elements.
3. You need to split twice: once the whole thing by commas, then the 3rd element by space.

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nT-H4I8Z).

```sql
create table sales_2019 (purchaseaddress text);
insert into sales_2019 values ('944 Walnut Street, Boston, MA 02215');

with 
 address_split_by_commas         as 
  ( select string_to_array(purchaseaddress::TEXT, ',') arr 
    from   sales_2019 )
,address_split_by_commas_trimmed as 
  ( select array_agg( trim(element) ) arr 
    from ( select unnest(arr) element 
           from   address_split_by_commas) a )
SELECT
    arr[1]                     Street,
    arr[2]                     City,
    split_part(arr[3], ' ', 1) State,
    split_part(arr[3], ' ', 2) ZIPCode
FROM
    address_split_by_commas_trimmed;
    

--      street       |  city  | state | zipcode
---------------------+--------+-------+---------
-- 944 Walnut Street | Boston | MA    | 02215
--(1 row)
```